# How to debug IIS + ARR Server Rewerite rules using Fiddler?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, fiddler, arr

I am trying to debug IIS + ARR in Reverse Proxy scenario. I have bunch of URL Rewrite rules that change the hostname of incoming request to another hostname, the requests come in via HTTPS. I need to capture the headers of the outbound request made by the ARR Reverse Proxy to the rewritten host.

The flow is:

Client calls https://**originalhostname**.com/foo/bar.aspx
ARR receives the requests and rewrites it to https://**newhostname**.com/foo/bar.aspx
After it hears back from **newhostname**.com ARR returns the response back to the client.

So i need to capture the request initiated by the ARR box for newhostname.com

I setup fiddler to intercept the outbound request following this [link](https://jasonsirota.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/using-fiddler-for-logging-of-iis-application-request-routing-arr-reverse-proxy-instead-of-failed-request-tracing-2/)

Outbound requests are visible in fiddler and are decryptable too but the hostname of the requests is not **newhostname** but instead are all to the **originalhostname**.
I do notice that a HTTPS Decryption tunnel is setup for the **newhostname**, but then i see the following in the fiddler logs and then the subsequent requests are all targeting **originalhostname**.

03:21:48:2877 Session #25 detaching ServerPipe. Had: 'direct->https/**newhostname**:443' but needs: 'direct->https/**originalhostname**:443'

What could be wrong? How can i debug this further?